# Referencing ui:params with hyphens in the name

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

After many years of avoiding JSF, I'm finally diving in but having problems doing the simplest of things. In the JSTL world, it's easy to reference things with hyphens in the name by doing `${requestScope['big-bad-invalid-name']}`.  However, that doesn't seem to work with a `<ui:param>` (or I'm simply starting with the wrong object--the likely issue).

I have a simple file that's referencing a template:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/main.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="require-data-main" value="/something" />
        <ui:define name="content">...</ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Sadly I can't figure out how to reference my param since `#{require-data-main}` is going to freak out due to the hyphens.  I've tried `#{param['require-data-main']}`, `#{viewScope['require-data-main']}`, `#{pageScope['require-data-main']}`, `#{applicationScope['require-data-main']}`.  My param doesn't seem to exist anywhere.

Update #1 -- I created another param without hyphens (camel case).  Nothing managed to resolve the value as I've tried above.  A plain `#{requireDataMain}` did, however.  I have a large number of JSPs already written. So I'm not too keen on changing my variable names.  I'd still love to find out how to reference the param with the hyphens in the name.

Has anybody seen my param?  Is there an alternate way to retrieve the param?

Answer (score -1):

A JSF page should use Managed Bean to access your java code. If you have a controller class for your jsf page, you could inject it to jsf using EL: `#{managedbean.field}` where `managedbean` is a following class:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "managedbean")
public class YourBean {
    private String field;
    //getter and setter for field
}
```

Hope that I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your statement, but it doesn't really address the question.  A managed bean is great when there is some logic that needs to be separated from the view.  What I'm talking about really just applies to the view itself (the template aspect).  Needing a managed bean for each view using a template would be a horrible thing.

Comment: Understood now. See [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-parameters-to-jsf-2-0-template-file/), I think it answers to your question completely.

Comment: Still not helpful (doesn't answer my question at all).  I know how to use the 'ui:param' element.  I just don't know to reference params with hyphens in the name.

Comment: If you use IDEA, you could easily rename all `require-data-main` to `requireDataMain` (including all occurrences in your jsp) pressing `Shift+F6`. But, that's not the answer. The [following link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=10) says that hyphens are invalid characters for attribute names: "because the name chosen for the scoped variable ... is not a valid Java identifier—because it contains a dash—and therefore the code will fail silently."

Comment: That's also incorrect.  You can use "invalid names" when you use the array notation: `#{pageScope['illegal-name]}`.  This has been working since 2003 (which was when that article was written, by the way), and still works today.

Comment: Didn't notice that my link is dated by 2003, huh. Sorry that I couldn't help you.